# Exception:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Tags: spring

I looked almost all answers but i could not find what is the problem in my code.Could you please help me anyone

Here is my JSp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Feedback Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="POST" commandName="userForm">
    <form:errors/>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Name :</td>
   <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Profession:</td>
   <td><form:radiobutton path="profession" value="Student" label="Student" /> 
    <form:radiobutton path="profession" value="Programmer" label="Programmer" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>mailinglist:</td>
   <td><form:input path="mailinglist" /></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
   <td>Country :</td>
   <td><form:select path="country">
    <form:option value="0" label="Select" />
    <form:option value="India" label="India" />
    <form:option value="United States" label="United States" />
    <form:option value="United Kingdom" label="United Kingdom" />
    <form:option value="Europe" label="Europe" />
    <form:option value="Canada" label="Canada" />
   </form:select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Feedback:</td>
   <td><form:textarea path="feedback" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Frameworks:</td>
   <td>
    <form:checkbox path="frameworks" value="Spring" label="Spring" /> 
    <form:checkbox path="frameworks" value="Hibernate" label="Hibernate" />
    <form:checkbox path="frameworks" value="Struts" label="Struts" />
    <form:checkbox path="frameworks" value="DOJO" label="DOJO" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><form:checkbox path="mailingList"
    label="Would you like to join our mailinglist?" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
       <!--<welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>-->
       <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/user.jsp</welcome-file>
      
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is my applicationContext.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    
    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
    
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->
    
    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->
     <bean class="com.test.UserController" >
     <property name="pages">
    <list>
  <value>user</value> <!-- page1 -->
  
    </list>
    </property>
    
      </bean>
    
     <bean id="viewResolver"
           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
           <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
           </property>
           <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
           </property>
       </bean>
    
</beans>
```

This is my user.java

```js
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.test;


public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String remark;

    /**
     * @return the username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @param username the username to set
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * @return the remark
     */
    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }

    /**
     * @param remark the remark to set
     */
    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }
    
    
}
```

and this is my Controller class

```js
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.test;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractWizardFormController;

   
public class UserController extends AbstractWizardFormController{
    public UserController()
    {
        setCommandClass(User.class);
        setCommandName("userForm");
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView processFinish(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o, BindException be) throws Exception {
       User user=(User)o;
        System.out.println("#####################User :"+user);
        return new ModelAndView("success","user",user);
    
}
}
```

Actual Bean:

```js
public class User {
 private String username;
    private String profession;
    private String country;
    private String feedback;
    private String[] frameworks;
    private boolean mailinglist;

    /**
     * @return the username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @param username the username to set
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * @return the profession
     */
    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    /**
     * @param profession the profession to set
     */
    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    /**
     * @return the country
     */
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    /**
     * @return the feedback
     */
    public String getFeedback() {
        return feedback;
    }

    /**
     * @param feedback the feedback to set
     */
    public void setFeedback(String feedback) {
        this.feedback = feedback;
    }

    /**
     * @return the frameworks
     */
    public String[] getFrameworks() {
        return frameworks;
    }

    /**
     * @param frameworks the frameworks to set
     */
    public void setFrameworks(String[] frameworks) {
        this.frameworks = frameworks;
    }

    /**
     * @return the mailinglist
     */
    public boolean isMailinglist() {
        return mailinglist;
    }

    /**
     * @param mailinglist the mailinglist to set
     */
    public void setMailinglist(boolean mailinglist) {
        this.mailinglist = mailinglist;
    }

    
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused as to what's intended/going on here. The form looks like it wants to submits values for 'profession' and other properties yet in your User bean class you have getters/setters for different properties like password and remark?

Comment: Then in your processFinish method you should be testing if you can get or set a property like user.getUsername() from the processed form rather than just having the object 'user'

Comment: yes..Actually i have added wrong bean i din't checked that one..now i am adding bean class now please check it once

Answer (score 0):

In your model add new method for URL of JSP

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView processStart(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException be) throws Exception {
   User user=new User();

    return new ModelAndView("UserJSPname","userForm",user);

  }
```

It basically initializes the empty User object and setting to model.

Comment: i have added the above code still i am getting same error:(

Comment: Post your complete error message-- If possible share your complete application

Comment: I am getting this error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userForm' available as request attribute

Comment: If i want to share the complete application 
where to share that one i don't have any idea